# Split a list of vectors based on named attribute in vector

Tags: r, list, split

I am looking for a way to split a list of vectors based on a named attribute in a vector.
Suppose I have a named list with vectors:

```
> v <- list("1"=c(col1=1, col2="a", col3="!"), "2"=c(col1=2, col2="b", col3="@"), "3"=c(col1=3, col2="b", col3="#"), "4"=c(col1=4, col2="a", col3="$"))
> v
$`1`
col1 col2 col3 
 "1"  "a"  "!" 

$`2`
col1 col2 col3 
 "2"  "b"  "@" 

$`3`
col1 col2 col3 
 "3"  "b"  "#" 

$`4`
col1 col2 col3 
 "4"  "a"  "$"
```

I would like to split out based on the value of `col2` for example so in this example I would like to have 2 lists:

- 1st list will contain all vectors that have `col2 = a`
- 2nd list will contain all vectors that have `col2 = b`.

---

I am looking for the output to be similar to the following:

For `col2 = a`:

```
$`1`
col1 col2 col3 
 "1"  "a"  "!" 
$`4`
col1 col2 col3 
 "4"  "a"  "$"
```

For `col2 = b`:

```
$`2`
col1 col2 col3 
 "2"  "b"  "@" 

$`3`
col1 col2 col3 
 "3"  "b"  "#"
```

**NOTE**: I would prefer a more generalized solution that groups by col2 but a binary solution would be OK because in this particular application I only have 2 possible values for col2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `split` and `sapply`.

```
split(v, sapply(v, function(x) x[["col2"]]))
# $a
# $a$`1`
# col1 col2 col3 
# "1"  "a"  "!" 
# 
# $a$`4`
# col1 col2 col3 
# "4"  "a"  "$" 
# 
# 
# $b
# $b$`2`
# col1 col2 col3 
# "2"  "b"  "@" 
# 
# $b$`3`
# col1 col2 col3 
# "3"  "b"  "#"
```

Comment: Or with `map` `split(v, map_chr(v, "col2"))`

Answer (score 2):

You can `rbind` first, i.e.

```
d1 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, v))
split(d1, d1$col2)
```

which gives,

> ```
> $`a`
>   col1 col2 col3
> 1    1    a    !
> 4    4    a    $
>
> $b
>   col1 col2 col3
> 2    2    b    @
> 3    3    b    #
> ```

If you wish to re-split on every row, then you can do,

```
lapply(split(d1, d1$col2), function(i)split(i, seq(nrow(i))))
```

which gives,

> ```
> $`a`
> $`a`$`1`
>   col1 col2 col3
> 1    1    a    !
>
> $`a`$`2`
>   col1 col2 col3
> 4    4    a    $
>
>
> $b
> $b$`1`
>   col1 col2 col3
> 2    2    b    @
>
> $b$`2`
>   col1 col2 col3
> 3    3    b    #
> ```